# Where can I find a List of Standard HTTP Header Values?

Tags: http, http-headers, web-standards

I'm looking for all the current standard header values a web server would generally receive.  An example would be things like "what will the header look like when coming from a Mac running OS X Leopard and Camino installed?" or "what will the header look like when coming from Fedora 9 running Firefox 3.0.1 versus SuSe running Konqueror?"

[PConroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163236/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-standard-http-header-values#163306) gave an [example from JQuery](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/test.html) tending towards what I'm looking for.  **What I want though are the actual example headers.**

Comment: Are you looking for a list of user-agents, or a specification of valid HTTP header syntax for any header? For good StackOverflow organization, those should be asked as two separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no set-in-stone list of user agent values. You can find lengthy lists (such as [this one](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/test.html) used by the [JQuery browser plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/browser/)).

Regarding other HTTP Headers, [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html)? It has all that information.

Actually, when searching for information on any protocol or standard, try to search for the RFC first.

Cheers.

Comment: For even better quality of your answer, maybe edit it to say "RFC2616"?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

With regards to user-agent, that is entirely up to the creator of the application. See this semi tongue-in-cheek [history of user-agent](http://www.webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/). In summary, there really isn't a canonical set of values. Microsoft based user-agents may change based on software installed on the local machine (version of .NET framework, etc).

Answer (score 2):

[IANA](http://www.iana.org/) keeps track of HTTP headers

> IANA is responsible for maintaining many of the codes and numbers contained in a variety of Internet protocols, enumerated below. We provide this service in coordination with the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF).

Which includes:

Message Headers

- Permanent Message Header Field Names
- Provisional Message Header Field Names

Here's [the exhaustive list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml) which was originally based on [RFC 4229](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4229)

Answer (score 1):

For the user agent, a quick google search pulled up [this site](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The list of HTTP headers is easily available on the W3 website:

- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

[PConroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2287/pconroy) also linked to the wikipedia page, which is more concise, and a little easier formatted:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers

However, the "User-Agent" header is a bad example, since there's no set response; the user-agent string is decided by the client so it can literally be anything. There's a very comprehensive [List of User Agents](http://user-agents.org/) available, but it's not necessarily going to cover any possible option, since even some toolbars and applications can modify the user-agent for Internet Explorer or other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The [chipmunk book from O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565925090/) is good as is [Chris Shiflett's HTTP reference](http://shiflett.org/books).

Oh, whoops, it's not a chipmunk.  It's a thirteen-lined ground squirrel.